# Properly specifying inverse associations on a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, set up like the below (much omitted for brevity):

```
class Note
  has_many :documents, as: :documentable
end

class Document
  validates :documentable, presence: true

  belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I'm creating a `Note` instance via sending a request to my API (`POST /api/v1/notes`) which is a conventional RESTful create.  The JSON looks like so:

```
{
  "note": {
    "description": "Test Description",
    "documents_attributes": [
      { "name": "document.name.pdf" }
    ]
  }
}
```

The goal is to have this JSON create a note as well as the nested documents, and set the `documentable` association to the newly created, parent `Note` object.  I've had no problems doing this via specifying inverse associations, however, it's a bit different when it's polymorphic.

How can I make sure that Rails sets the documentable on the child documents?  Right now it's throwing a `422 Unprocessable Entity` because validation isn't passing because `documentable` isn't being set.

Comment: Try removing `validates :documentable, presence: true` and see if both the `note` and the corresponding `document` gets saved to the database. If it works, then its possibly the issue with the timing of the events. When `note` is validated, `rails` probably is doing validation of the associated `document` object as well, which fails as `note` itself is not saved yet (still in the validation phase).

Comment: I think the validation needs to be based on the actual database field names. Like `validates :documentable_type, :documentable_id, :presence => true`

Comment: @Dharam that works, and I know that this is the problem.  When I've had this problem it has been solved by specifying the inverse associations.  My question is: how can I specify the inverse associations on this polymorphic association?

Comment: On another one of my associations that is a simple has_many/belongs_to, when I specify `inverse_of` it then passes validations as well as sets the associations properly.

Comment: It seems that there is a polymorphic_inverse_of method, but it does'nt seem very well adopted or documented.
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/polymorphic_inverse_of

Comment: I think `inverse_of` applies to join models. In your case as there is no join model, I don't think it applies.

Comment: @Dharam I've used `inverse_of` to solve this problem plenty of times without a join model.  It was a has_many/belongs_to however.